# Solr random results within top "n"

Tags: solr

I have a slightly different case. I have few categories of documents (say with facet field values catA, catB, catC, ....). I want to find "N" documents of either catA or catB. The query will be like "catA OR catB". Now the first 100 search result docs have identical scores. I only want to retrieve 10 documents. Because catA docs were indexed first, the 10 documents I get are all of catA. What I want in this case is to get 10 docs randomly chosen out of the top 100. I know I can retrieve 100 documents and then pick 10 randomly. But, 100 is an example figure, it can be just 10 or 1000's. It is good if the random queries with paging can do it, but it doesn't. One way I can think of is to make a first query to get say 100 docs, find the no. of docs with the same top score (say "m"), if it is bigger than 10, make a second query with raws=m. Can anyone throw some ideas to do this better?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Utility Field used for random sorting. 
From here: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_2/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html

To get random sorting order, you need to use a random dynamic field name. For example, you will need to configure schema.xml:

```
<types>
    ...
    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" />
    ... 
</types>
<fields>
    ...
    <dynamicField name="random*" type="random" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    ...
</fields>
```

Examples of queries:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&fl=name&sort=random_1234%20desc
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&fl=name&sort=random_2345%20desc
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&fl=name&sort=random_ABDC%20desc
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&fl=name&sort=random_21%20desc
```

Note that multiple calls to the same URL will return the same sorting order.

Comment: Thanks Ovidiu. Yes, I know i can use random sorting as you have mentioned. What I want is to get random order within docs that have the same score and the rest as normal (i.e. not random but in rank order). Not sure if this is possible do in a single query. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can use `sort=score desc,random_1234 desc`, like this: `http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=*:*&fl=name&sort=score%20desc,random_1234%20desc`.

Comment: Thanks.  Doing random query randomizes all results (not only the ones that has the same score). Adding a different field as a secondary sort (in addition to score) seems to work better (although not ideal).

Comment: Actually your answer is correct Ovidiu. Using random_<RandVal> as a secondary sort field does exactly what i want. Thanks!